# How to edit in the textfield as an integer using a if statement in an action listener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield

For a bingo game, I have a textfield that shows random numbers. I use an action listener for a button "next ball" to change the number in the textfield. However, I want to add a letter before every number using an if statement. The number is both an integer and a textfield. How to use the if statement here?

Comment: Please give more to work with

Comment: I could share my code with you. Maybe you could understand what I mean

Answer (score 1):

When the button is clicked, you need an action to be fired.

```
jBtnSelection.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    selectionButtonPressed();
    } 
});
```

This adds a simple listener, but you should look up specific listeners for mouse clicked or entered and such.

Now you need the conditional that adds a random letter to the end of a string.
I suggest finding the random index of a letter in a string that holds the alphabet... Then, add that string to the Textfield.

```
String s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

       int x = (int)(Math.random()*26); // random int between 0-25
       String letter = ""+s.charAt(x); //concatenates
       textField.setText(textField.getText()+letter);
```

If you want to "add a letter" based on a conditional....
A switch conditional would be cleaner as well... but I' am going to show you the "if" conditional below....

```
if(textField.getText().equals("1"))
{
   String s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

       int x = 1 //index of a letter
       String letter = ""+s.charAt(x); //concatenates 
       textField.setText(textField.getText()+letter); // concatenates text.

}
```

This is pretty basic stuff, so I am going on the fact that you are able change parts of the code... which has all the essence of the program that you are looking for ... to something that fits your needs more, as I am only working with what you have provided in your description.

Comment: (1-) variable names should not start with an upper case character. Some of your variable are correct. Some are not. Be consistent. Also. there is no need to invoke revalidate() (that is only when you add components to a visible GUI). When you change the property of a component the component is smart enough to repaint itself (by invoking revalidate() and repaint() for you).

Comment: Better. Remember when you answer a question you should be promoting standard Java/Swing programming practices. (down vote removed).

Answer (score 1):

> I have a textfield that shows random numbers.

Why are you using a JTextField. The random number is for display so I would suggest you should be using a JLabel.

> The number is both an integer and a textfield.

This doesn't make sense the number is randomly generated and then converted to a text string which you display in a Swing component.

> How to use the if statement here?

Well, using an if statement is a brute force way to do this. But the code would be something like:

```
int number = getNextRandomNumber();
String text = null;

if (number <= 15)
    text = "B" + number;
else if (number <= 30)
    text = "I" + number;
....

label.setText( text );
```

A better way to do this (so you don't need nested if statements) would be something like:

```
String[] letters = new String[]{"B", "I", "N", "G", "O"};
int number = getNextRandomNumber();
int letterIndex = (number - 1) % 15;
String text = letters[letterIndex] + number;
label.setText( text );
```

Comment: Can I share my code? Maybe you can tell me my mistake.Thanks for your help

Comment: @FatemahN, You should always post code that demonstrates your problem. Note the code you post should be directly related to the stated problem only. This is called a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (follow the link). The code should compile. So all you need is a JFrame, with a JLabel and a JButton. When you click the button you will update the label with the text. So the entire code will be 20-25 lines of code. The point of a `SSCCE` is to force you to simplify the problem so you can solve the problem.